# How can I read in a binary file in q?

Tags: kdb

I have a file that has 362000 32bit floats, its 1000 rows by 362 columns, what it means is the first 362 floats correspond to row 1, and the next 362 floats is row 2, and so on.  Is there a way in q, to read this into a table?

-Thanks.

Comment: Can you upload a two-line sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 1: command can be used to read and format binary files into kdb

```
reals: (enlist 4;enlist"e') 1: `:fp32file
```

You may need some adjustments based on endianness, see https://code.kx.com/q/ref/filenumbers/#1-binary-files

This will give you a list of all 362000 32 bit floats. To get that into a table,

```
colNames: `$"col",/:string til 362 / or whatever your column names are
reals: flip 362 cut raze reals / turn list into a 362x1000 array
flip colNames!reals / create a dictionary, convert to table
```

EDIT: Actually, instead of reading it into a list, you can specify that you've got 362 columns with

```
reals: (362#4;362#"e") 1: `:fp32file
flip colNames!reals
```